# I grew fat due to age-related changes. Will I gain muscle mass more easily now?

Tags: weight-loss, weight-gain, muscle-mass, muscle-gain

I'm a 25 year old male and I added 20 pounds of fat in the last 3 months. My father had a similar experience at the same age, so I guess it's age-related.

Before my mid-20s, gaining muscle, actually any type of mass, was really hard for me, regardless of how much I ate or exercised. Now, I have the opposite situation, I can't lose weight. So, my idea is the following: instead of trying to lose weight, in my current situation, I should focus on gaining muscle mass.

So, how likely is it that I will gain muscle mass more easily now? Or is growing fatter not usually related to gaining muscle mass?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately as you get older you are likely to add roughly a pound of fat to your body per year.

So no it doesn't mean you will put on muscle more easily.

On a more serious note unusual rapid weight gain is probably worth a visit to the doctor to ensure it's not a metabolism issue or thyroid.

It could just be stress, but that's a lot of weight to put on in a short period of time.